# Async implementation of EmpApi's Subscribe method

Tags: lightning-web-components, asynchronous, js, empapi, publish-subscribe

Need to wait the Subscribe operation to be done to get the message from Platform Event to use that message in the Apex call in LWC.

You can check the code below.

```
// Apex method call to insert metadata records
insertMetadata({ records: toBeInserted })
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        this.loading = false;
        if (result) {
          try{
            // Subscribe to a channel
            this.subscribeToEvent();
            // Handle successful subscription
            console.log('Subscribed to channel successfully');
            console.log(this.message.get('data').payload);
            console.log(this.message.get('data').payload.SuccessSize__c);

            
            this.successSize += this.message.get('data').payload.SuccessSize__c;
          }
          catch (error) {
            // Handle subscription error
            console.error('Error subscribing to channel:', error);
          }
          loadEvent.reportSuccess(this.successSize);
          loadEvent.reportError(this.errorSize);
          loadEvent.resume();
        }
        else{
          this.errorSize += this.message.get('data').payload.ErrorSize__c;
          console.log('SUCCESS SIZE:::' + this.successSize);
          console.log('ERROR SIZE:::' + this.errorSize);
          loadEvent.reportSuccess(this.successSize);
          loadEvent.reportError(this.errorSize);
          loadEvent.resume();
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.loading = false;
        loadEvent.reportError(data.length);
        loadEvent.resume();
        console.log('error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
      });
      console.log('END OF AN APEX CALL!');
    }

// Subscribe method
subscribeToEvent(){
      subscribe(this.channelName, -1, (message) => {
        // Handle received Platform Event
        console.log('Received Platform Event: ', JSON.stringify(message));
        this.message = this.createMessageMap(JSON.stringify(message));
        console.log(this.message);
      })
      .then(response => {
          // Handle subscription response
          console.log('Subscription response: ', response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
          // Handle subscription error
          console.error('Error subscribing to Platform Event:', error);
      });
  
      // Handle error when subscribing to the Platform Event
      onError(error => {
        console.error('EMP API error: ', JSON.stringify(error));
        this.showToast('Error', 'Error subscribing to Platform Event', 'error');
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subscribe before calling your Apex code. Your code waits until the Apex code has already been called.

Example:

```
this.subscribeToEvent().then(
  () => insertMetadata({ records: toBeInserted })
).then(
  () => { /* handle response here */ }
)
```

Note that subscribeToEvent should return a Promise:

```
// Subscribe method
subscribeToEvent(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
      subscribe(this.channelName, -1, (message) => {
        // Handle received Platform Event
        console.log('Received Platform Event: ', JSON.stringify(message));
        this.message = this.createMessageMap(JSON.stringify(message));
        console.log(this.message);
      })
      .then(response => {
          // Handle subscription response
          console.log('Subscription response: ', response);
         resolve(response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
          // Handle subscription error
          console.error('Error subscribing to Platform Event:', error);
          reject(error);
      });
  
      // Handle error when subscribing to the Platform Event
      onError(error => {
        console.error('EMP API error: ', JSON.stringify(error));
        this.showToast('Error', 'Error subscribing to Platform Event', 'error');
        reject(error);
      });
    );
}
```

I'm not entirely sure all of this code is valid at first glance, but this should help.

Comment: `this.subscribeToEvent().then(
  () => insertMetadata({ records: toBeInserted })
).then(
  () => { /* handle response here */ }
)`
Can you please detail the code sample above? Can i get the message received from Platform Event in the "handle response here" part?

Comment: @batuayyildiz no. The function that was subscribed will handle the platform event.

Comment: thank you, this approach solved the issue!